# how to pull id from push() firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone please explain me why firebase unique id starting with '-' ?

I have two questions:

How can i get the id from push, if there is any return to this request?

```
firebase.database().ref('carts/-KJp9LdQkEN1DtuCLjfP/pro').push({
  name:name,
  amount:am
});
```

On this part i'm trying to handle the callback snapshot. All my attempt to extract the data from this json have failed.

```
JSON.parse(data) == error
snapshot.key(); == error
data[0] == error

firebase.database().ref('carts/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These keys (often called "push ids") start with a `-` because that is the first character in the dictionary used to generate them. See this [blog post explaining how they are generated](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

If you are trying to get the push id of a item you're adding, you can do that like this:

```
var newRef = firebase.database().ref('carts/-KJp9LdQkEN1DtuCLjfP/pro').push();
console.log(newRef.key);
newRef.set({
  name:name,
  amount:am
});
```

If you want to determine the key of an item in a listener, you can do that like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('carts/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key); // carts
  var data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

More likely if you're listening for children, you'd get the key with this:

```
firebase.database().ref('carts/').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key); // -KJ....
  var data = snapshot.val();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Or like this:

```
firebase.database().ref('carts/').on('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(cartSnapshot) {
    console.log(cartSnapshot.key); // -KJ....
    console.log(cartSnapshot.val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank u very much!
the first solution does work perfectly!
although the second just give the the location, like in this example i get "carts"

Comment: That's correct. If you're listening for children (e.g. with `child_added`), you'd get the key of each child with `snapshot.key`. I'll add some more code.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen please rectify the syntax error console.log(cartSnapshot.val();) and can you please tell me how can i get value of only one child - i dont want to iterate all the children!

Comment: When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hi, how do we retrieve a specific object (when it was added to a list e.g `/users` using `push()`) Do we need to supply the key! if yes, how to get that key to supply it to param e.g. `/users/${key}`, maybe I am not understanding this right, sorry if my question is silly.